# Haskell Stack Implementation

Tags: loops, haskell, stack

this is my first time posting on StackOverflow. I am learning Haskell and am trying to make a function `test` that manipulates a stack. It takes an integer list as input and then does the following:

1. If the number is even:

   - If the number is 24 and there are no occurrences of 2 in the input list up to the current index, then we throw an error.
   - Otherwise, we push the number to the stack.
   - E.g. `list = [0,1,2,3,4,24]`. There is an occurrence of 2 in the list, so we push 24 to the stack.
2. If the number is odd:

   - If the top of the stack == current number - 1, we pop from the stack. Otherwise, we throw an error.
   - If the stack is empty after popping the stack, we display a "success" message.

At the moment I have managed to implement the stack, where I think the `push`, `pop`, `peek` operations have `O(1)` complexity, though I believe there must be a better way to implement it:

```
emptyStack :: [a]
emptyStack = []

push :: a -> [a] -> [a]
push item xs = item : xs

pop :: [a] -> [a]
pop [] = error "Cannot pop from empty stack."
pop xs = tail xs

peek :: [a] -> a
peek = head
```

And for the `test` function, this is what I have came up with this monstrosity which doesn't iterate through the list and the `stack = emptyStack` does not make sense:

```
test :: Integral a => [a] -> Either String [a]
test [] = Left "Empty input list"
test (x:xs) | even x = if x == 24 && notElem 2 (x:xs) then Left "Error!"
                        else Right (push x stack)
            | odd x = if null (Right (pop xs)) then Left "Success~" else
                        (if peek stack == x - 1 then Right (pop stack)
                        else Left "Not 1 less than current number!")
    where stack = emptyStack
```

How should my `test` implementation be modified to suit the requirements mentioned at the beginning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another possible way forward: don't hardwire the stack. Make your function accept *both* a stack and a list of instructions, and make it return *both* the modified stack and the modified list of instructions (or an error). Be careful not to confuse the stack with the list of instructions, as they have the exact same type. Perhaps you could focus on performing a *single* step at first, and then expand your solution to one that consumes the whole list of instructions.

Comment: A (somewhat subtle) problem with your code: `null` on an `Either` is always `True` for `Left` values and always `False` for `Right` values. (Why does `null` work *at all* with `Either`? Well, it's a long story related to something called `Foldable`.) You are always using null with a `Right` value. Perhaps you meant something different, like checking directly if `pop xs` is empty? Oftentimes, performing a pattern-match on a list (`case pop xs of [] -> .... z : zs -> ....`) is a better way to detect that the list is empty.

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks for the reply! Regarding your first comment, I meant that the function should check if the stack is empty immediately after popping an element from the stack, hence I used ```Right (pop xs)```. For the second comment, can you tell me what you mean by "a list of instructions"? Does that refer to the requirements at the beginning, or was it meant to be the input list of integers?

Comment: Yes, I meant the list of integers. I still don't see why do you use `Right (pop xs)` though. You are calculating `pop xs`, wrapping it on a `Right`, and calling `null` on that. Why add the `Right`? You can experiment in ghci typing something like `null (Right ([]::[Int]))` or `null (Right [1::Int,2])`. You'll see that it always returns `False`!

Comment: @danidiaz  I was trying to match the type signature for my function, so I included ```Right``` to match the ```Either String [Int]```. But now I see your point now, there is in fact no reason to add the ```Right``` there.